# Filtering in MVC Razor using LINQ

Tags: linq, razor

In my view, I have a model `StudentListModel` which is as follows:

```
public class StudentListModel
{
    public IEnumerable<StudentModel> SModel { get; set; }
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
}
```

In my view I want to filter `SModel` and bind it to a textbox. I am using the following code:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(score => score.SModel.Where(x=>x.StudentId==1))
```

But I am getting the following error:

> Templates can be used only with field access, property access,
>   single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer
>   expressions.

Which is the best way to filter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot directly filter like that because `@html.textboxfor` cannot display a list.

You can use the following code:

```
@foreach (var item in @Model.SModel.Where(x=>x.StudentId==1))
{      
    <li>@Html.DisplayFor(score => item.StudentName)</li>
}
```